# AutoCompleteTextView float hint

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, autocompletetextview, android-textinputlayout

I've tried a lot, but can't make work an `AutoCompleteTextView` float hint using the `TextInputLayout` from support.

It's possible or I need to use an external library?

Comment: You can definitely do it using Design Library. Post your code so I can help you better.

Comment: Please explain what "can't make work" means. In other words, you need to provide us with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No .

#### design library itself is enough

include like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Id"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, i have an especific layout that doesn't work, i'm trying to figure out what was my mistake.

Comment: what are you trying to show on that link? totally useless. Can you actually point it to a specific class or line in the code?

Comment: @delkant there was code for answer,  but over the time repo is updated.  Thanks for pointing

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: 2020, and this still works. though i would like to point out that there would be a small design issue since `TextInputEditText` adds a padding which `AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't .So, Adding a padding `android:padding="16dp"` to `AutoCompleteTextView`  will make it look exactly similar as before

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a little bit late but here is the trick:

Create the following Class,

```
public class AutoCompleteTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    private boolean mIsHintSet;
    private CharSequence mHint;

    public AutoCompleteTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AutoCompleteTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (child instanceof EditText) {
            mHint = ((EditText) child).getHint();
        }
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (!mIsHintSet && ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this)) {
            setHint(null);

            EditText editText = getEditText();
            if (editText == null) {
                return;
            }
            CharSequence currentEditTextHint = editText.getHint();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentEditTextHint)) {
                mHint = currentEditTextHint;
                editText.setHint("");
            }
            setHint(mHint);
            mIsHintSet = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now Add this lines to your layout file and see the magic

```
<com.example.AutoCompleteTextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textColorDarkHint"/>
</com.example.AutoCompleteTextInputLayout>
```